# How does a single verb construct work when it has both honorific and humble auxiliaries?

Tags: honorifics

An example textbook sentence:

> かかるついでに、見たてまつり給はむや　How about looking at him (Genji) on this occasion?

たてまつる is humble auxiliary,　給ふ（給う） is honorific. Does this reflect a relationship between 3 people, where:

speaker - 給ふ - addressee - たてまつる - Genji

So speaker is both elevating addressee's status with 給ふ honorific while also humbling him before Genji?

Comment: Looks to me like you have answered your own question.  Everything you said is correct.

Comment: I'd suggest adding a Kobun or Genji tag to this question.

Answer (score 1):

Your great, concise description agrees with the following Q&A :

> http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1132656341 
>    （僧都が尼君に）「この世にののしり給ふ光源氏、かかるついでに見たてまつり給はむや」 （源氏物語）

ののしる today means "to curse, badmouth, ..." but in Genji's time it meant "to be famous" among other meanings.

This Q&A page also explains the penultimate 「む」

> 「む」には(1)推量・予想、(2)意志・決意、(3)適当・勧誘、(4)仮定、(5)婉曲という五つの意味がありますが

In this text, it is (3)適当・勧誘 ==  適当…［～がよい］, 勧誘…［～しませんか］

( One minor point:  the addressee 尼君 is female, so the speaker is both elevating addressee's status with the 給ふ honorific, while also humbling [her] before Genji. )

```
            見たてまつり reminded me of "A cat may look at a king."
```